# From GPS coordinates and local time to UTC 0 (Zulu Time)

Tags: web-services, time, gps, coordinates, utc

I have a  geographical coordinate associated to a local timestamp. From this information I would like to get the UTC 0 time in that location at that time.

For example let's say I have a coordinate pointing to a place in Rome, with a local timestamp of 15-Nov-2013 13:00. Rome in November (considering daylight saving time) is at UTC+1. So the output should be: 15-Nov-2013 12:00.

Of course a function that takes in coordinates and local timestamp and outputs the UTC 0 time would need to know to which country a certain coordinate is pointing to, and would also need to know the daylight saving time policy in that country.

Do you know if there is such a service  ?

Thanks

Comment: Its always an error to associate a coordinate to an local time stamp; much better is a tripple: coordinate, UTC time, timezone in form (Country/City)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something which does the geo part:
http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

The actual computation part should be easy (local timestamp + offset)

Comment: That works if you're looking for the *current* time, but an arbitrary time may or may not have the same offset depending on whether DST was active. Unfortunately I haven't found anything better.

Comment: I added an answer with a Google API that includes the timestamp in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a [Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/#Usage) that can do this. It takes the location *and* the timestamp, and returns the `rawOffset` and the `dstOffset` which must be added together. Then you can modify your timestamp accordingly to get the UTC time.

```
utcOffset = rawOffset + dstOffset
utcTimestamp = timestamp - utcOffset
```

Of course, it expects a UTC timestamp, so the result may still be off by an hour if you are near the DST border.